# Closing ECSlidingViewController menu

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'd like to implement my sliding menu in a way that pressing the Menu button will show my menu and pressing Menu again would hide it. But I can't understand how to do it with ECSlidingViewController. Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ECSlidingViewController has methods for this: `anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:`, `anchorTopViewToLeftAnimated:` and `resetTopViewAnimated:`.

Example in your top view controller:

```
[self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:YES]
```

ECSlidingViewController provides a category for UIViewController adding this `slidingViewController` property.

You may also want to use ECSlidingViewController's `currentTopViewPosition` to determine if your button should show your menu or hide it in the current context.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the category I had not seen that and was exactly what I was looking for too.

Answer (score 6):

I have came up with this question and above answer helps me to resolve it. But I just need to add more detailed answer with code example, so others might get benefit from this if they faced such a problem.

```
- (IBAction)showSlidingMenu:(id)sender {
   [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:YES];
   if ([self.slidingViewController currentTopViewPosition] == ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredRight) {
      [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
   }
}
```

- Please note I am animating the top view controller to Right, so I am checking whether top view position is *ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredRight*.
- Similarly top view position has *ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredLeft* if you are animating to the left.
- If menu is not showing top view position will get *ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionCentered*.

+1 for the question and accepted answer

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to "ECSlidingViewController sample project" you need to put these 4 lines in ViewWillAppear of FirstTopController(e.g TransitionViewController):

```
self.slidingViewController.topViewAnchoredGesture = ECSlidingViewControllerAnchoredGestureTapping | ECSlidingViewControllerAnchoredGesturePanning;
self.slidingViewController.customAnchoredGestures = @[];
[self.navigationController.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.dynamicTransitionPanGesture];
[self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

These 4 lines are being used in delegate method of tableview. It might be possible you're not using tableview so these 4 lines are not calling.

Best of Luck..