# ECSlidingViewController crashes on second swipe

Tags: ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm building a new project using ECSlidingViewController v2.  The first time I swipe to open the left under view, it works great.  But when I swipe the second time, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash.  The reference is to the NSMapTable in the controller.

```
- (void)updateTopViewGestures {
    BOOL topViewIsAnchored = self.currentTopViewPosition == ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredLeft ||
                         self.currentTopViewPosition == ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredRight;
    UIView *topView = self.topViewController.view;

    if (topViewIsAnchored) {
       ...
    } else {
        ...
--->    [self.customAnchoredGesturesViewMap removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking reference from @uiroshan answer [Closing ECSlidingViewController menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802064/closing-ecslidingviewcontroller-menu/23707787#23707787)

You can use the following code:

```
- (IBAction)showSlidingMenu:(id)sender 
{
   [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:YES];
   if ([self.slidingViewController currentTopViewPosition] == ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredRight) 
   {
      [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
   }
}
```

Here,

- I am animating the top view controller to Right, so I am checking whether top view position is ***ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredRight***
- To animating the top view controller to Left
  ***ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredLeft***